# Compute midnight timestamp in UTC +0 using DateTime python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp, utc

I need to scrap an online database which contain +/- 24h of data at fixed interval using an API query which contain a timestamp. Because i don't know where the server is choose something simple like midnigth UTC.

I found lot of documentation on SO to compute UTC aware of local zone. I'm actually using this protocole to get actual UTC Date :

```
import datetime
myDate = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) 
print("TZ INFO = ", myDate.tzinfo) # return UTC+00:00
print("DATE ", myDate) # return 2017-07-08 14:14:24.137003+00:00
print("ISO DATE = ", myDate.timestamp()) # return 1499523264.137003
```

First question, why the `timestamp()` returned take in account the local timezone : `1499523264.137003` is equal to ~16h15, so `UTC +2` corresponding to France Zone. Why `timestamp()` doesn't return only the UTC + 0 timestamp ? How can i get an `UTC + 0` timestamp ?

Second question, i try to generate a midnight date to query the API, so like i saw on many post on SO, i try to use the `replace()` function :

```
myDate = myDate.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0,microsecond=0).astimezone(pytz.utc)
print (myDate) # return 2017-07-08 00:00:00+00:00
```

But when i try to `print (myDate.timestamp())` return another time a UTC + 2 timestamp, so 2AM of 2017-07-08. How can i get midnight UTC + 0 timestamp easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/) module since it makes timezone and date calculations easy to perform.

pendulum is aware of daylight savings time schemes, as indicated here for London and Paris. It can also provide the UTC time shorn of an adjustment for daylight savings time. When you need to provide an adjustment to UTC you can simply using the `replace` method in conjunction with UTC.

```
>>> import pendulum
>>> pendulum.create(2017,7,9,0,0,0,0,'Europe/London')
<Pendulum [2017-07-09T00:00:00+01:00]>
>>> pendulum.create(2017,7,9,0,0,0,0,'Europe/Paris')
<Pendulum [2017-07-09T00:00:00+02:00]>
>>> pendulum.create(2017,7,9,0,0,0,0,'UTC')
<Pendulum [2017-07-09T00:00:00+00:00]>
>>> t = pendulum.create(2017,7,9,0,0,0,0,'UTC')
>>> t.replace(hour=+2)
<Pendulum [2017-07-09T02:00:00+00:00]>
```